# Replace blank spaces from arguments to run command

Tags: java, ffmpeg, replaceall

I'm using Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String) to cut some songs with ffmpeg.
But when my song has a name with a blankspace it doesn't work ...

So before I cut the song, I want to replace every blank space of my songs by "\ ".

I did that :

```
String in = directory+songs.get(i);
String out = directory+"trimed_"+songs.get(i);
in.replaceAll(" "," \\ ");
out.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");
String str = "ffmpeg -t 1 -i "+in+" -vcodec copy "+out;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
```

But it doesn't replace anything at all when I print str, am I missing something ?

**Update** :  I tried every ideas given bellow and I didn't find a way to fix the problem. Hence, I replaced the blankspaces by "_" and it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String in = directory+songs.get(i);
String out = directory+"trimed_"+songs.get(i);

/* in = in.replaceAll("\\s","\\\\ ");
   out = out.replaceAll("\\s","\\\\ "); 
*/

in = "\"" + in + "\"";
out = "\"" + out + "\"";

String str = "ffmpeg -t 1 -i " + in + " -vcodec copy " + out;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
System.out.println("Command executed " + str);
```

**Note**: I tested this code myself its working fine.
If it still not working then execute the command manually by copying the `str` from log and trace the error

Comment: Without replaceAll functions for in and out ?

Comment: Still doesn't work, now the songs without any blank spaces aren't working anymore

Comment: for example with a song name with blank space str is equals to :

ffmpeg -t 1 -i "/home/chris/Music/then dance.m4a" -vcodec copy "/home/chris/Music/trimed_then dance.m4a"

Comment: I tried with your last update and it doesn't work str is still equals to : 
ffmpeg -t 1 -i /home/chris/Music/then dance.m4a -vcodec copy /home/chris/Music/trimed_then dance.m4a
The blank spaces aren't replaced !

Comment: Try now it should replace `" "` with `"\ "`

Comment: Now the str is equals to : ffmpeg -t 1 -i /home/chris/Music/then\ dance.m4a -vcodec copy /home/chris/Music/trimed_then\ dance.m4a but the command isn't runned by Runtime... I don't have the output song produced by ffmpeg